# How can Java code be quickly converted to .NET (specifically, ASP.NET)?

Tags: java, .net, asp.net

1. Are there any tools available to simplify the conversion?
2. What percentage of Java code is converted exactly to .NET code by these tools?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [IKVM](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), an extremely popular Java XQuery/XSLT engine by Michael Kay, uses IKVM.

> IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java
>   for Mono and the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework. It includes the following
>   components:
>
> ```
> * A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
> * A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
> * Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability
> ```

http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: A performance point to consider.  Java code relies on the Java class libraries.  These have been converted to .NET as well but reside in a 26MB assembly.  Loading this assembly can impact application startup time depending on your usage.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one
http://mayaf.org/janett/

Janett translates Java syntax, constructs and calls to Java libraries to C# / .Net counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Java is roughly equivalent to c#, so translating to c# should be relatively straightforward.

The path from a Java webserver to ASP.NET is less clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to the Java Language Conversion Assistant from Microsoft.  I think they may have dropped support, but now ArtInSoft seems to have a related product:

http://www.artinsoft.com/pr_jlca.aspx

There's also Octopus from Remotesoft:

http://www.remotesoft.com/octopus/

The issue with porting from Java is usually not so much the language itself, which is pretty similar to C#, as it is the libraries.

Of course, a web app will present an additional layer of complexity.  If the app doesn't have too much code at the page rendering phase, it shouldn't be very difficult.  If the page is riddled with code, then you may be better off re-writing it than trying to port directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using J#?  It's no longer supported but if you're just trying to get onto a .NET language, that might be the fastest path.